# If $AE$ and $BF$ are medians drawn to the legs of a right $\Delta ABC$, find the numerical value of $\frac{(AE)^2 + (BF)^2}{(AB)^2}$ .

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, problem-solving

> If $AE$ and $BF$ are medians drawn to the legs of a right $\Delta ABC$, find the numerical value of $$\dfrac{(AE)^2 + (BF)^2}{(AB)^2}$$

**What I Tried**: First of all, I didn't quite understand what the question meant by numerical value. For example I took $AB = 5$ and $BC = 6$ in *Geogebra*, and the particular value I got to be was around $1.97$ an so on, but is this the answer for every right triangle? If yes, how? 
Also what does "numerical value" mean here?

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In right $\triangle ACE$,

$$ AC^2 + (\frac{BC}{2})^2 = AE^2$$

In right $\triangle BCF$,

$$ (\frac{AC}{2})^2 + BC^2 = BF^2$$

Adding

$$ \dfrac{5}{4}(AC^2 + BC^2) = AE^2 + BF^2$$

$$ \therefore \dfrac{AE^2 + BF^2}{AB^2} = \dfrac{5}{4} = 1.25$$

**As medians also form right triangles with legs, due to Pythagoras theorem it follows that this ratio is true for all right triangles.**

According to question, $\angle C$ is right angle, $AB$ is hypotenuse. Probably this yielded the incorrect value of $1.97$.

Comment: Oh I got it, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the formulas for the medians and also the Pythagorean theorem.

https://www.math10.com/en/geometry/median.html

Say $a,b$ are the legs and $c$ is the hypotenuse.

$$m_a^2 =  \frac{1}{4}\cdot(2c^2 + 2b^2-a^2)$$
$$m_b^2 =  \frac{1}{4}\cdot(2c^2 + 2a^2-b^2)$$

Sum these two and you get:

$$m_a^2 + m_b^2 =  \frac{1}{4}\cdot(4c^2 + a^2 + b^2) = \frac{1}{4}\cdot(5c^2) = \frac{5}{4}\cdot c^2 $$

The problem you are given asks you to find

$$\frac{m_a^2 + m_b^2}{c^2}$$

From the previous equality this is now obviously $$\frac{m_a^2 + m_b^2}{c^2} = \frac{5}{4}$$